# Typescript Function Generics

Tags: typescript

Since TS doesn't allow the syntax of the below:

```
anObject['aKey'] = 'aValue';
```

I am creating the below interfaces and inherit all objects from it:

```
interface KeyIndexable {
  [key: string]: any;
}

interface ObjectA extends KeyIndexable {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}
```

But now when I am trying to create a generic function variable as the below:

```
let x: <T extends KeyIndexable>(t: T) => void;
x = (a: ObjectA) => console.log('x');
```

I got an error saying `Type KeyIndexable is missing the following properties from type ObjectA`.
So in this case how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript doesn't stop you to access object properties by string key:

```
let anObject = {};
anObject['aKey'] = 'aValue';
```

Or maybe you should adjust `tsconfig` for your needs.

Your last error is about differet types of function declaration and implementation.
When you write this:

```
let x: <T extends KeyIndexable>(t: T) => void;
```

it means "`x` *is a function that takes one argument of any type that extends* `KeyIndexable` *and returns nothing*".
But then you are trying to assign to `x` value of type "*function that takes one argument of type* `ObjectA` *and returns nothing*". These types are different as you can see. So TS can't understand how to check parameter of x: should it by `ObjectA`, or just something like `KeyIndexable`.
So `extends` in your generic is for this case:

```
let x: <T extends KeyIndexable>(t: T) => void;
x = (a) => console.log('x');

let a: ObjectA = { a: 'a', b: 1 };
x(a); // ObjectA is accepted here
```

If you want dynamicaly create your function and have different parameter types, you should better create some factory that returns a function with parameter type you need

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. `ObjectA` extends `KeyIndexable` so it should meet the type constraint?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show what `extends` is for in this case